# When efcore creates new instances of dbsets

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-3.0

While using efcore, we simply define `Dbset<T>` in database context and then efcore takes care of everything. however, these dbsets are object type therefore efcore must create new instances of them at some point.(I don't know, maybe using 'new' keyword or sth else.) So i was wondering when and where and how this magic happens.

Comment: EntityFrameworkCore is open source, you can look for yourself: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: Actually, I went through efcore code on github, but I couldn't find this part due to the very large code base and tons of classes and files that existe in ef core source

Comment: When a new migration added, it will update your SnapShot, I think this is where all the magic happens.

Comment: They are set by calling `IDbSetInitializer.InitializeSets` method [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/src/EFCore/DbContext.cs#L112). The default implementation is [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/src/EFCore/Internal/DbSetInitializer.cs#L48).